# wake on lan over the internet

Tags: networking, router, wake-on-lan

I'm trying to use teamviewer to remotely wake up and use my main desktop from a laptop.

I was able to wake up the machine in question through the local network however I can't seem to be able to make this happen through the internet.

I have setup port forwarding on my router with logging enabled, assigned a static ip address to it (in my case 192.168.0.2), in order to avoid ARP issues.

I'm using wireshark to try and troubleshoot however while I'm able to see the packet show up even when trying to send from the internet, when the pc is asleep nothing happens.

I can see the port forwarding rule being logged on the router so I guess something its reaching the router but pherhaps somehow failing to reach the network card? anything else I could try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WOL - Wake On Lan over internet](https://superuser.com/questions/266009/wol-wake-on-lan-over-internet)

Comment: Setting a static IP address does not avoid ARP issues. You must also create a static ARP mapping on the router so the router’s ARP table always has an entry mapping the sleeping client’s IP address to its MAC address.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [machine wakes only on local magic packet](https://superuser.com/questions/1219721/machine-wakes-only-on-local-magic-packet)