# Wake on Lan over the Internet (Wake on WAN?)

Tags: windows-10, networking, router, wake-on-lan

I have managed to get WoL to work perfectly for when I'm turning a PC on from within the same network.
I have also properly port-forwaded (UDP port 9) and can use Depicus's software to wake the same PC on the Internet setting, but still while I'm connected to the same network. If I'm no longer connected to the same network, WoL (or is it Wake on WAN now?) doesn't work. Can please someone help, I've been researching for too long I'm about to go mad

Comment: Does this answer your question? [machine wakes only on local magic packet](https://superuser.com/questions/1219721/machine-wakes-only-on-local-magic-packet)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a static/permanent ARP mapping in your NAT gateway router's ARP table so it knows which MAC address to address the magic packet to. That is, you need to map the target machine's LAN IP address to the target machine's Ethernet NIC's MAC address, in the ARP table of the NAT gateway router. Otherwise, when the router gets the magic packet, it will know the destination IP-layer address but not which Ethernet-layer address to send it to, so it will be broadcasting ARP requests to try to learn the MAC address it needs, but the target machine won't answer because it's asleep.

Comment: wait, so i understand, because I've read about this but i can't find the setting anywhere (i'll look again though) so i'll still be using my public ipv4 ip (192.168.xxx.xxx) and mac address (and udp port ofc) to send the magic packet from anywhere in the world and my router will catch it?

Comment: I'm not sure if I found the ARP Table but i found a "Device List" where I can see the device I'm trying to wake and I can see the connection type (Ethernet), the device name, MAC address, IPv4 and IPv6 addresses and all these are correct. am I looking at the right place?

Comment: Router admin UIs are all different. You'll have to read your own manual. There's no guarantee that the factory firmware even lets you create static/permanent ARP mappings, so you may have to upgrade to OpenWrt or similar if you want a way to make this work. If the place you're looking is just reporting what it sees on the network, then it's only going to be correct if the target machine was awake recently enough that the information has not timed out and been deleted yet. ARP table entries generally only last something like 2 minutes.

Comment: i can't find an ARP table and at this point I'm not sure my Router's admin panel has one, I've been looking for it in the manual but again, nothing...

Comment: When I try waking up a PC on the LAN from the internet, without any ARP stuff, it actually works... unless the PC has been asleep for a long time (say about 48h... even after 24h it works). Is it because the router somehow keeps track of the PC during a certain period before forgetting it?

Comment: @PierU Yes my first guess would be that your router is using a very long timeout on its dynamic ARP table entries.